# Looking for something like subtracting Counters to get negative keys for the difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I've recently started learning python, and I am attempting to optimize a scrabble solving program to practice.  I have written a working program but, after adding the ability to take into account blank tiles, I realized I was doing it wrong, and it was taking ages to run.  I was building a giant list of possible racks, then running my program against each possible rack.  Now, to optimize things, I am looking to build a list of available letters, and then once I have a list of possible words, score them against the rack (to account for blanks).

What I was doing before was:

```
for item in word_list:
    for letter in item:
        if item.count(letter) > players_rack.count(letter):
            valid_words.append(item)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this using Counter()
What I would want to do, is subtract `Counter(word)` from `Counter(letters_to_work_with)` and if any items are negative...which is probably not possible with Counter(), say that it can't be a valid word.

Is there a data type that would work better here?  Or is there a method I am just not seeing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear to me - posting at least some examples inputs and outputs might help (ie : "given this and this as input, I'd like to get this as output").

It's indeed possible to substract a `Counter` from another one but that doesn't yield the expected result. Now you can still substract values for specific keys, ie

```
>>> c1 = Counter("word")
>>> c2 = Counter("oawrc")
>>> [(k, c2.get(k, 0) - v) for k, v in c1.items()]
[('r', 0), ('o', 0), ('w', 0), ('d', -1)]
```

Comment: An example might be 

    `c1= Counter("arpgjdabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") 
    c2= Counter("pepper")

    print(c1 - c2)

    [('a', 1).........('p', -1).....]`

I think you answered my question though.  It is possible to subtract counters, but it just eliminates the item from the list as opposed to making the key negative.

Comment: Didn't know you could substract Counters - one learn something new everyday, year after year ;). Fixed my answer, thx.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.2 and higher, `Counter` has [a `subtract` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract) which does exactly what you want, preserving 0 and negative values the way the actual `-` operator does not. It operates in place, so you'd do:

```
letter_counts = Counter(letters_to_work_with)
letter_counts.subtract(word)
# Alternatively, though it won't short-circuit, you could do:
# if min(letter_counts.values()) < 0:
if any(v < 0 for v in letter_counts.values()):
    ... not valid ...
```